# Automated source code manipulation with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I would like to be able to automatically process a file with a regular expression and perform a more or less arbitrary action on the match contents. For my most recent need I would like to be able to find every instance of Grid.Row="some int" in a xaml file and increment that row number by one whenever it is larger than X. Yes, for this particular example even though this is legacy code the better approach would be to restructure so this same problem does not need a hack solution the next time around. However, I have encountered the need to do this sort of thing more than once, so I'll ask anyway.

Do any of you know of tools that already exist that would let me do something like this before I go write something simple myself? I googled around for a bit but didn't see anything besides basic regex tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that nothing like this exists from the lack of feedback. I built a quick javascript app to fit my needs. If I have time to make it flexible enough I'll update this answer with a github link. I've started using it to do things like start every word with its correct lowercase letter, split camelcase into words for documentation, etc. Really surprised nothing official exists yet.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind would be [retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina). Although the 'if bigger than X' part is not too difficult, the incrementation won't be easy to implement. Both would be very easy if it allowed to define functions for the substitution but afaik it doesn't.